# How to fix the Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed error?

Tags: r, stargazer

I'm trying to print a table of combined lm's in Rstudio using Stargazer and I keep getting this message:

> Error in if (nchar(text.matrix[r, c]) > max.length[real.c]) { :
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

This is the code I'm using:

```
monthlyreturns_bp <- cbind(Fstats(monthly_returns[,'France']  ~ 1, from =  0.05),
                           Fstats(monthly_returns[,'Canada']  ~ 1, from =  0.05),
                           Fstats(monthly_returns[,'Germany'] ~ 1, from =  0.05),
                           Fstats(monthly_returns[,'Japan']   ~ 1, from =  0.05),
                           Fstats(monthly_returns[,'UK']      ~ 1, from =  0.05),
                           Fstats(monthly_returns[,'US']      ~ 1, from =  0.05))

colnames(monthlyreturns_bp) <- c("France", "Canada", "Germany",
                                 "Japan", "UK", "US")

stargazer(monthlyreturns_bp,
          type     = "text", 
          out      = "Breakpoints of Monthly Return Levels",
          titile   = "Breakpoints of Monthly Return Levels",
          summary  = FALSE, 
          colnames = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()` and use the [reprex-package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.